# Using Theta Notation Find Worst Case

Tags: analysis, asymptotic-complexity

I was assigned to find the worst case runtime of this algorithm using theta notation.

As this is a new, complicated concept to me I am slightly confused. The equation is below

```
for i->0 to n do //1
     for j->i to 4i do //2
          for k->0 to j do //3
               A [i] = A[i] + A[j] + A[k] //4
          end
     end
end
```

I'll go through what I think is correct so far.
For the 1st line I understand that it is runtime n, that is easy to understand. For the 2nd line I have written out a table and I believe that it is 3n but I am not 100% sure. For the 3rd line I am not sure at all. The 4th line is 1.

That is what I have so far but I am not sure. If anyone could assist me that'd be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: `I believe that it is 3n but I am not 100% sure` FYI that's correct, because you are going from `i` to `4i`.

Comment: Now for the 3rd line how would I go about calculating that? Each iteration it runs through I think 3n times as well. Correct me if I'm wrong. If that's correct then should I multiply lines 1-3 to get 9n^3 and then add one? The final answer being 9n^3+1? And then O(n^3)?